# The permutizer of a subgroup H of G is defined to be the subgroup generated by all cyclic subgroups of G that permute with H

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

The permutizer of a subgroup H of G is defined to be the subgroup generated by all cyclic subgroups of G that permute with H, i.e $P_G(H)=\langle  x\in G \mid  \langle x \rangle H = H \langle x \rangle \rangle$. Let $ G=D_8 = \langle a , b \mid  a^4= b^2 = (ab)^2  \rangle$ and $ H= \langle a \rangle $ and $ N = \langle a^2 \rangle $ then how calculate $ P_{G/N}(HN/N)$ ,  $ P_G(H)N/N$  ,  $P_{G/N} (H/N)$ and $ P_G(H)/N$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Since $H$ has index $2$ in $G$, it is normal, and thus $P_{G}(H) = G$. This shows that the second subgroup is $G/N$. Now $G/N$ has order $4$, and thus it is abelian, and thus all subgroups are normal, and thus permute with everything. So the first subgroup is also $G/N$.